# Problems with autostratup tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, autostart

I have to start tomcat automatically at the boot of my machine(Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS).

so i done search on internet and i discovered that i have to put the command that start my tomcat in /etc/rc.local

so this is my file:

> ```
> touch /var/testing1234
>
> sh /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/startup.sh
>
> touch /var/testing123465
>
> exit 0
> ```

when i reboot the file testing 1234 is created but the file testing123465 is not created, what can be the problem?,please gel me, I'm going mad with this thing.

Comment: SOLVED just put sudo before command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the .47 version? There's 7.0.26 as an dpkg, simply do an `apt-get install tomcat7`...

Add a `&` at the end of the sh line.

Comment: Ok, and now i can create the other file, but tomcat can't start anyway.

Comment: It looks like you don't need the latest version - undo/uninstall whatever you did and just use the version included in the distro. 

Have you found the error log for tomcat?